# HP P1102 printer not working properly

Tags: printing, hp

I had to re-install Ubuntu 12.04.  My HP LaserJet P1102 is now printing at a very low dpi (for want of a better description).  It prints in a very rough draft quality only.

I went into "Settings" and added the printer again, but no improvement.

Do I need a plug in?  If so, how do I go about installing it?

Update:  I just tried printing from LibreOffice Writer and it seems to be working fine.  However, when I print out an email from gmail I have the problem of very poor quality.